# Using JMS transaction across inbound and outbound queues

Tags: spring-integration

I am using Spring Integration to read a message from the queue and write it out to multiple queues. In case of *any* failure, I want the message to be written to a failure queue and none of the output queues should have received the message. To achieve this, how can I set up my transactions? I am using a message driven channel adapter on the inbound and a jms outbound channel adapter. I am using a splitter to create multiple messages (based on number of output queues) that are provided to the jms outbound channel adapter. 
The flow will be running as a standalone java application.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that using JMS stuff:

1. You should configure `redelivery` policy for the inbound `queue` to `0`
2. And provide a `DLQ` for that.

In that case on the TX rollback your message won't be redelived to your listener one more time and just will go to the `DLQ`.

See more info in the JMS spec.

**UPDATE**

The solution according Gary's advice: https://gist.github.com/artembilan/e7aff2afbf4ff4308159

Comment: As @Artem said, it is much simpler to use a DLQ. But, if you really want to do it in Spring Integration, it can be done - start a new transaction before the splitter (use a transactional gateway or a transaction advice/interceptor on the splitter's input channel - if it's direct). With propagation `REQUIRES_NEW`, a new transaction will be started. Then, put an error-channel on the message-driven channel adapter; handle the error (write to the error queue).

Comment: Added a Gist link to the answer